# Accessing the body of a split entrySet in Apache Camel

Tags: java, split, hashmap, apache-camel

The body of my message contains a HashMap.

I split this message by its entrySet:

```
.from(FROM)
   .aggregate(...)

   // create an iterable
   .transform(simple("${in.body.entrySet()}"))

   // split over the Iterable
   .split(body())
      .process(new ReadMapEntry())
      .to(TO)
   .end()
.end();
```

Now trying to retrieve these entries in the processor. Closest I got was trying to cast this. I've found similar examples using ArrayList, but I can't get them to work for this... in this sort of works, but it triggered an unchecked cast warning due to the generics of Map.Entry.

```
public void process(final Exchange ex) throws Exception
{     
   Map.Entry<A, B> entry = (Map.Entry<A, B>) ex.getIn().getBody(Map.Entry.class);
   (...)
}
```

**Solution**

My objective here was to avoid the warning associated with casting over an inherited class. I ended up making use of the `simple` keyword in the end. This way I could pass the map's value into the processor (thus avoiding the unchecked cast warning) and accessing the key through a header.

```
.from(FROM)
   .aggregate(...)

   .split(simple("${in.body.entrySet}"))
      .setHeader(KEY_VALUE_AS_HEADER, simple("${body.getKey}"))
      .setBody(simple("${body.getValue}"))
      .process(new ReadMapEntry())
      .to(TO)
   .end()
.end();
```

```
public void process(final Exchange ex) throws Exception
{     
   A value = ex.getIn().getBody(A.class);
   B key = ex.getIn().getHeader(KEY_VALUE_AS_HEADER, B.class);
   (...)
}
```

Comment: Can you include the actual code you used to try to iterate over the map?  If you debug and check the map variable, is it null?

Comment: @Tim, Map looked good when the whole map was iterated over in the `process(new ReadMapEntry())`. It was your standard `for(Map.Entry<A,B> : Map.entrySet())`. The change I'm trying to implement is only having the process handle one map entry at a time. I updated the code to show where the process is called. I never manually iterate over the map anymore... unless I'm using it wrong, I thought `.transform` would create this list of entries, and `split(body())` would pass them one-by-one to the processor.

Comment: Is it just the compiler warning you're worried about, or does the route actually fail? If it's just the compiler warning, you've three choices as I see it: just ignore the warning, annotate to ignore the warning, or check the cast before casting.

Comment: @Screwtape you're right, it's the warning, which I'm just trying to avoid. I think I solved it though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use a simple Bean and directly inject the Body with the correct type.

```
// simple POJO, does not implement Processor interface
public void readMap(@Body Map.Entry<A, B> mapEntry) {     
     // use mapEntry (message body) directly instead of extracting it from Exchange
     mapEntry.[whatever]
}
```

Then you call it in your route

```
.method(new ReadMapEntryBean()) // if Bean contains only 1 method
```

or

```
.method(new ReadMapEntryBean(), "readMap") // if there are other methods
```

The processor interface is quite old, clumsy and hard to test. POJOs are much easier to use and they work very well with Camel.

See [Parameter Binding Annotations](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/parameter-binding-annotations.html) and [Bean Integration](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/bean-integration.html) from the Camel Docs for more details

Comment: I like this idea, but I ended up revamping the code completely by abusing the `simple` keyword. :)